# Method annotated with @Retryable not getting invoked when called from batch process method

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-aop, spring-retry

Method annotated with `@Retryable` not getting invoked when called from batch process method.

```java
@Service
public class HierarchyRetryOperationImpl implements HierarchyRetryOperation {

    private final HierarchyService hierarchyService;

    @Inject
    public HierarchyRetryOperationImpl(
            HierarchyService hierarchyService){
        this.hierarchyService= hierarchyService;
    }

    @Recover
    public HierarchyNode reportFailureReadHierarchyForBatch(SystemException cause) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    @Retryable(value = SystemException.class , maxAttempts = 4,backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
    public HierarchyNode readHierarchy() {
        return hierarchyService.readHierarchy( );
    }
}
```

Comment: If it isn't called you aren't calling it.

Comment: Where is this service used in your batch job and when are you expecting it to be retried?

Comment: I have used it in batch process method '@Override
    public ResultHolder process(String string) {
     
        ResultHolder resultHolder = new ResultHolder();

                HierarchyNode root = hierarchyRetryOperation.readHierarchy();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                throw new SkippableException(e);
            }
        }
        return resultHolder;
    }'

'@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class SpringRetryConfig {
}'

Exp:
org.springframework.retry.TerminatedRetryException: Retry terminated abnormally by interceptor before first attempt

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Can u please help me out i have placed the code in the comment section above, stating from where the method is invoked.